# Error connecting python to neo4j using py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I wrote the following python code to neo4j using py2neo

```
 from py2neo import Graph
 from py2neo import neo4j,Node,Relationship
 sgraph = Graph()
 alice = Node("person",name="alice")
 bob   = Node("person",name="bob")
 alice_knows_bob = Relationship(alice,"KNOWS",bob)
 sgraph.create(alice_knows_bob)
```

but i got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 258, in get
response = self.__base.get(headers=headers, redirect_limit=redirect_limit, *
*kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py",line
966, in get
return self.__get_or_head("GET", if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit,
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py",line
943, in __get_or_head
return rq.submit(redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py",line
452, in submit
return Response.wrap(http, uri, self, rs, **response_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py",line
489, in wrap
raise inst
py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.ClientError: 401 Unauthorized

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurr ed:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "neo.py", line 7, in <module>
sgraph.create(alice_knows_bob)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 704, in create
statement = CreateStatement(self)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\cypher\create.py", 44,in__init__
self.supports_node_labels = self.graph.supports_node_labels
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 1078, in   supports_node_labels return self.neo4j_version >= (2, 0)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 956, in  neo4j_version
return version_tuple(self.resource.metadata["neo4j_version"])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 213, in metadata
self.get()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 261, in get
raise Unauthorized(self.uri.string)
py2neo.error.Unauthorized: http://localhost:7474/db/data/
```

can anyone please help me.This is the first time i writing python code to connect to neo4j.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using Neo4j 2.2, authentication for database servers is enabled by default. You need to authenticate before performing further operations. Read [documentation](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#authentication).

```
from py2neo import authenticate, Graph

# set up authentication parameters
authenticate("localhost:7474", "user", "pass")

# connect to authenticated graph database
sgraph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

# create alice and bob
...
```

---

From the same [documentation](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#authentication),

> Py2neo provides a command line tool to help with changing user
>   passwords as well as checking whether a password change is required.

For a new installation, use:

```
$ neoauth neo4j neo4j my-p4ssword
Password change succeeded
```

> After a password has been set, the tool can also be used to validate
>   credentials

```
$ neoauth neo4j my-p4ssword
Password change not required
```

Comment: @ComputerFellow I get an error saying neoauth: command not found.. Any idea on this?

Comment: authentication can be disabled completely by editing the value of the dbms.security.authorization_enabled setting in the conf/neo4j-server.properties file.