# 403 Error When Trying To Connect After Upgrading To Neo4J 2.2.4

Tags: python, neo4j

I am unable to connect to the local database through Python (using `py2neo`) after upgrading Neo4j Community Edition (Windows) from 2.1.6 to 2.2.4.

I tried

```
from py2neo import authenticate, Graph, Node

authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "neo4j")
graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
alice = Node("Person", name="Alice")
graph.create(alice)
```

I get the following error at `graph.create(alice)`

```
py2neo.error.GraphError: HTTP GET returned response 403
```

I have followed the tips to a similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29986433/799188) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098402/799188), but I still get the above mentioned error.

The same bit of code (without the need to authenticate) works on 2.1.6.

Please could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the initial password to something else than `neo4j`.

Then it should work.

Comment: How can that password be changed? I am running Neo4j on AWS-EC2 and when trying to access the neo4j browser on my local machine, I uncommented the 7474, 7473 and bolt global access in conf file, but every time try to log in, I get error: "
 ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection in 5000ms". Is there any way to change password on EC2 through command line / modification in some file, or is there any way to get the browser fully connected?